# Does Windows Phone 8 lock screen support animated backgrounds like Android Live Wallpapers?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does Windows Phone 8 lock screen support animated backgrounds like Android Live Wallpapers? I found this link on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx  Which overviews how an app can change the background of the lock screen.